# How do I unset or get rid of a bash function?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

If you set or export an environment variable in bash, you can **unset** it.  If you set an alias in bash, you can **unalias** it.  But there doesn't seem to be an **unfunction**.

Consider this (trivial) bash function, for example, set in a *.bash_aliases* file and read at shell initialization.

```
function foo () { echo "bar" ; }
```

How can I clear this function definition from my current shell?
*(Changing the initialization files or restarting the shell doesn't count.)*

Comment: All that being said, `unfunction` would be a nice name for a command :-)

Comment: @Johannes Rössel: *zsh* has it.

Comment: Hm, indeed. Still, I find PowerShell's way of dealing with all this slightly more intuitive and consistent :-)

Answer (score 163, accepted):

The *unset* built-in command takes an option, `-f`, to delete functions:

```
unset -f foo
```

Form the *unset* entry in the *bash* manpage:

> If -f is specified, each name refers to a shell function, and the function definition is removed.

Note: `-f` is only really necessary if a variable with the same name exists. If you do not also have a variable named `foo`, then `unset foo` will delete the function.

Comment: that's what i was missing.  i'd found the `-f` parameter in *export* but hadn't found it in *unset*.  thanks.

Comment: @XavierStuvw: `unset` is not an external command, it is part of the shell (*bash* in this case); try `man bash` and find the entry for [`unset`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-unset) (the manage is quite large, `unset` is under the `Shell Builtin Commands` section).

Comment: as of bash 4.3.30, `-f` is necessary even if no variable is named foo,

Comment: Unset all function at once: `unset -f $( declare -F | cut -c 12- )`

Comment: It seems that if you defined a function multiple times, it cannot be unset no matter what.  This has driven me crazy.

Comment: `unset -f foo` is the command for `zsh` as well.

Comment: @YanKingYin I just ran into the "cannot be unset" issue. Maddeningly, the fix seems to be start another terminal.

Answer (score 7):

See `help unset`:

```
unset: unset [-f] [-v] [-n] [name ...]

Unset values and attributes of shell variables and functions.

For each NAME, remove the corresponding variable or function.

Options:
  -f    treat each NAME as a shell function
  -v    treat each NAME as a shell variable
  -n    treat each NAME as a name reference and unset the variable itself
    rather than the variable it references

Without options, unset first tries to unset a variable, and if that fails,
tries to unset a function.

Some variables cannot be unset; also see `readonly'.

Exit Status:
Returns success unless an invalid option is given or a NAME is read-only.
```

There is neither `unset --help` nor `man unset` unfortunately.

Comment: There is not `man unset` because it is a _built-in_ command and for the _built-in_ commands there is instead `help`. For some _built-in_ command it exists an external executable too.  In case of doubt try e.g. `type mycommnad`. For example `type unset` and it will answer you  `unset is a shell builtin`. If you want to know if it exists the executable too try `which echo` (another buikt-in) and it will say where it is. The `--option_long` is typical of the executable command. Try `echo --help` and `/bin/echo --help`. `:-)`.

Comment: @Hastur Feel free to add your comment to the answer by editing its tail. If the reviewers approves of it, you'll be awarded 2 points.

Comment: ...thanks for the thought Xavier: it was more for you than to complete the answer; I guess you missed that it was a _built-in_ command and for them you have to use `help` instead of `man`. (Not really true because you find them in `man bash` in the chapter _SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS_ or directly  with `man BASH-BUILTINS`...).  It's cosy that under a bash shell you can simply ask for `help` and you will receive the list of _built-in_ command `:-)`. (Try `help help` and `man man` too).

Comment: @Hastur You may well complete the answer for the benefit of all readers. Then we can delete the comments to make good riddance of small-print clutter.

Comment: Yes @Hastur, please do. I was about to do it but since I didn't write the comment I can't easily get the markup for it => too much manual effort for me to make it feel worthwhile. :)

Comment: `info zsh unset` or `info bash unset` will bring up documentation

Answer (score 0):

I recently wanted to completely uninstall `nvm` and reinstall it, and get rid of any of its environments. Turns out that getting rid of it does not seem to because much of `nvm` is in part implemented as a boatload of shell functions that are sourced into your shell via `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`, or wherever you added those sourcing commands it told you to when you first installed it.

Baffled at first by `which nvm` returning nothing yet clearly the `nvm` command and others were still being found, I eventually discovered via `declare -F` that it's a bunch of shell functions. I didn't want to just kill the shell and start a new one (for reasons not relevant here), so I cleared `nvm` functions out of that shell with this:

```
for F in `declare -F | grep -e nvm | cut -f 3 -d\ `; do unset -f $F; done
```

Some variations on that might be helpful to someone out there that for whatever reason wants to do something similar and can't restart a new shell or doesn't want to.